# Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! Object for dependency "@babel/core" is empty.
npm ERR! Something went wrong. Regenerate the package-lock.json with "npm install".
npm ERR! If using a shrinkwrap, regenerate with "npm shrinkwrap".

**Please help me with this**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObTGO.png)

Comment: tried the command but failed...npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack

Answer (score 0):

Add "@babel/core": "^7.12.10", or whichever is the most recent version, to your list of dependencies in your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when i used create-react-app which uses yarn to install dependencies, and later when i tried to install dependencies with npm this error popped to me - looking at the image the OP posted, it seems he is in the same boat using both yarn and npm.

I believe if i used yarn to install the dependencies in the first place then this would have not happened - and anyway it's not a good idea to mix the two.

### To fix the issue - assuming you will only continue using npm:

- remove yarn.lock and package-lock.json
- run "npm install" again